# Discord bot send msg in specific channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I know this has been asked before, but I couldn't find a solution that worked for me. But I want my discord bot to (when I write a command) send a message on a specific channel and that channel only.

Currently, I have only the basic files and folders in my workspace + a commands folder.
The index file looks like this:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const client = new discord.Client();
const prefix = '>';
const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs
 .readdirSync('./commands/')
 .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
 const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
 console.log(`${client.user.username} is online`);
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ + /);
 const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

 if (command === 'cmd') {
  client.commands.get('cmd').execute(message, args);
 }
});

client.login('CLIENT_ID');
```

and then there's a folder called "commands" at the same level as index.js, and it contains cmd.js which looks like this

```js
const client = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
 name: 'cmd',
 description: 'cmd',
 execute(message, args) {
  const channel = client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL_ID').send('message');
 },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client` is not something you get from requiring the `discord.js` module. It is created at the beginning of your bot, and you can fetch your client instance through [`message.client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client)

```js
const channel = message.client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL_ID').send('message');
```